# Convert List<T> to List<(T,T)>

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

I have a `List<System.DateTime> MonthlyDates`

I would like without iterating to convert `MonthlyDates` into a `List<(,)>`

So if `MonthlyDates` is contains (forget that these are strings they have been parsed to `DateTime`)

```
..."7/31/17", "8/31/17", "9/29/17", "10/31/17",  "11/30/17",  "12/29/17"...
```

I would like a new `List` of date pairs like this:

```
("7/31/17", "8/31/17") , ("8/31/17", "9/29/17"), ("9/29/17", "10/31/17"), ("10/31/17",  "11/30/17"), ...
```

So a conversion from `List<T>`, to `List <(T,T)>`

Comment: What do you have against iterating?  Linq does this under the covers anyway.

Comment: and wha't's the end time for the last pair?

Comment: when you learn to do things declaratively vs imperatively, your programming is getting stronger imo

Comment: You know what's annoying? When people provide an example but no actual explanation. If you put some thought into the logic such that you could actually explain it to us, as you should, then you might even be able to go a way to solving the problem yourself.

Comment: Version .Net 4.6.2

Comment: I could easily solve the problem. It is the LINQ version that eludes me

Comment: So.. edge cases. Are the dates always sequential? What happens when there is an odd number of elements?

Comment: guaranteed to always be even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var prior = MonthlyDates[0];
var result = MonthlyDates.Skip(1).Select(d => 
    {
        var buf = prior;
        prior = d;
        return (buf, d);
    });
```

Add the `.ToList()` on the end if you really need to, but you'll often find you get better performance by skipping it.

Comment: @Jamiec Oh, I missed that. Will delete, then re-work it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) to transform your data in a deferred manner. LINQ query variable itself only stores the query commands. The actual execution of the query is deferred until you iterate over the query variable via `foreach` or methods that materialize query to some collection or result like [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist), [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray), [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count), etc.

So you can use next query:

```
var datePairs = monthlyDates.Zip(monthlyDates.Skip(1), (first, second) => (first, second));
```

[`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip) method applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, producing a sequence of the results. In this example we use `monthlyDates` twice as both collections with an offset of 1 element. This allows a collection of neighbouring items to be iterated sequentially, combining them into a single collection.